# Different result with online compiler and visual code

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been getting different results if I run my program on Visual Code or an online compiler. I think this is an version issue, but I am not able to pin point the exact piece of code that is causing it. The program takes in two polygon vertices and prints the vertices of the intersection of the two polygons.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

struct point{
    double x, y;

    // point operator = (point const& obj)
    // {
    //     point res;
    //     res.x = x + obj.x;
    //     res.y = y + obj.y;
    //     return res;
    // }
};

int main()
{
    int n,m;
    std::vector<point> polyA, polyB;

    std::cin >> n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        point temp;
        std::cin >> temp.x >> temp.y;
        polyA.push_back(temp);
    }
    polyA.push_back(polyA[0]);

    std::cin >> m;
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        point temp;
        std::cin >> temp.x >> temp.y;
        polyB.push_back(temp);
    }
    polyB.push_back(polyB[0]);

    auto determinant = [](point a, point b, point c) -> int
    {
        double deter = (double)a.x*((double)b.y-(double)c.y) - (double)b.x*((double)a.y-(double)c.y) + (double)c.x*((double)a.y-(double)b.y);
        return (0 < deter) - (0 > deter);
    };

    auto lineEq = [](point A, point B) -> std::vector<double>
    {
        double a1 = B.y - A.y;
        double b1 = A.x - B.x;
        double c1 = a1*A.x + b1*A.y;
        return {a1, b1, c1};
    };

    std::vector<point> polyInter = polyB;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;polyInter.begin()+ j != polyInter.end();j++)
        {
            if(determinant(polyA[i], polyA[i+1], polyInter[j]) >= 0)
            {
                if(determinant(polyA[i], polyA[i+1], polyInter[j+1]) >= 0)
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    
                    std::vector<double> eq1 = lineEq(polyA[i], polyA[i+1]);
                    std::vector<double> eq2 = lineEq(polyInter[j], polyInter[j+1]);

                    point temp;
                    double det = eq1[0]*eq2[1] - eq2[0]*eq1[1];
                    temp.x = (int)((eq2[1]*eq1[2] - eq1[1]*eq2[2])/det);
                    temp.y = (int)((eq1[0]*eq2[2] - eq2[0]*eq1[2])/det);
                    
                    polyInter.insert(polyInter.begin()+j+1, temp);
                    j++;
                    
                }
                
            }
            else
            {   
                if(determinant(polyA[i], polyA[i+1], polyInter[j+1]) > 0)
                {
                    std::vector<double> eq1 = lineEq(polyA[i], polyA[i+1]);
                    std::vector<double> eq2 = lineEq(polyInter[j], polyInter[j+1]);

                    point temp;
                    double det = eq1[0]*eq2[1] - eq2[0]*eq1[1];
                    temp.x = (int)((eq2[1]*eq1[2] - eq1[1]*eq2[2])/det);
                    temp.y = (int)((eq1[0]*eq2[2] - eq2[0]*eq1[2])/det);

                    polyInter.insert(polyInter.begin()+j+1, temp);
                }
                polyInter.erase(polyInter.begin() + j);
                j--;
            }            

        }

    // for(unsigned int i=0;i<polyInter.size(); i++)
    // {
    //     std::cout << polyInter[i].x << " " << polyInter[i].y << " ";
    // }
    // std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    if(polyInter.empty())
    {
        std::cout << 0 << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    polyInter.pop_back();
    polyInter.insert(polyInter.end(), polyInter[0]);
    polyInter.erase(polyInter.begin());

    std::cout << polyInter.size() << std::endl;
    for(unsigned  int i=0;i<polyInter.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << polyInter[i].x << " " << polyInter[i].y << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Code Input and Result:

```
4
0 0 10 0 10 10 0 10
4
5 -1 11 5 5 11 -1 5
8
10 4 10 6 6 10 4 10 0 6 0 4 4 0 6 0
```

Tutorialspoint online compiler (or any other online one):

```
4
0 0 10 0 10 10 0 10
4
5 -1 11 5 5 11 -1 5
7
10 4 10 6 6 10 4 10 0 6 0 4 6 0
```

Can any one suggest where the problem is?

Comment: The actual differing results would be good info.

Comment: Sorry about that, just edited it

Comment: You are changing your container while iterating over it. I didn't look at the code in detail but this really smells like undefined behaviour because of that.

Comment: `for(int j=0;polyInter.begin()+ j != polyInter.end();j++)` Looks wrong. `if(determinant(polyA[i], polyA[i+1], polyInter[j]) >= 0)` is not doing what you think it is. `if(determinant(polyA[i], polyA[i+1], polyInter[j+1]) >= 0)` Same issue.

Comment: Yes, I am adding newer points and iterating over them in the next loop. Is there a better way to do that?
What is wrong with the lambda function?

Comment: Off the top, on the last iteration of the loop when `j` points to the last element, `polyInter[j+1]` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an index out of bounds.

Comment: yes, missed that. That indeed does solve the problem. I think vs code is able to detect that and somehow solve it in the background(it shouldn't be doing that). Thanks